# Bison style: is using my own stack bad? Are globals bad?

Tags: c++, unix, yacc, flex-lexer

My question is basically "what constitutes good style in YACC / Bison?" and, relatedly, whether or not I am letting Bison do the things it is good at.

For example, I find that my Bison program relies to a greater extent on globals than my original code did. Consider the following:

```
 prog : 
      vents{ /*handle semantics...*/ } 
      unity{ /*handle semantics...*/ } 
      defs;
```

If I want to pass information between the two curly brace-delimited blocks after "vents" and "unity", I think that using a global variable (technically, a variable with file-level scope and internal linkage) is the best I can do from an information-hiding standpoint. Any variable I declare within these blocks is local to its block (I think...), and the other designated places I can put C++ declarations result in file-level scope.

If I could inject a variable declaration into the "yyparse()" function, this would better suit my needs. Is there a hook for this sort of code, or some other way to inject such a variable? Or are globals just an accepted part of using Bison?

It has also occurred to me that maybe I am not supposed to even want to pass information between these sections in this way. But passing everything around using just $$, $1, $2, etc. seems difficult to me. Am I just not "getting it"?

I find one of my global variables to be particularly questionable even if I accept the rest of them. It is of type std::stack and relates to the input language's support for conditionals.

When I encounter a conditional ("if/else") in my compiler input, this results in the eventual emission of three assembly language labels, comprised of a text string followed by a number pulled from the sequence.

So, I am acquiring a sequence number when I first encounter the "if", pushing it onto a stack (since "if" structures can be nested), and then using it later (via "peeks" or "pops") to construct the necessary labels and jumps, e.g after my condition, my "if" block, and my "else" block.

I tried to make this work using something like $-2 instead, but found that this identifer pertained not to the beginning of my conditional, but to the end of whatever block was just compiled. The system abstracted over by $ seems to pertain to the code as read from left to right, without any concept of how the structures within it are nested.

I don't expect you all to make this work for me... but was I at least on the right path with trying to use $$, $1, $-1, and so on? It's quite possible I just gave up too soon, and/or that I would benefit from taking a clean sheet approach, i.e. from throwing out my old *ad hoc* code altogether.

Is that the case? Or is my thrown-together approach with its std:stack and its globals OK?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the difficulty of avoiding using global variables, I barely use them to signal errors or similar things.

Think about the parser, what should it produce? An abstract syntax tree..

How is it made? It's a n-ary tree in which every node contains some information and just its children, so there's no need for global variables.

I'll give you a peek of a language I'm writing just to give you the idea:

```
bexp:
  bexp T_PLUS bexp { $$ = new ASTBExp($2,$1,$3); }
  | bexp T_MINUS bexp { $$ = new ASTBExp($2,$1,$3); }
  | bexp T_TIMES bexp { $$ = new ASTBExp($2,$1,$3); }
  | bexp T_DIV bexp { $$ = new ASTBExp($2,$1,$3); }

uexp:
  raw_value { $$ = $1; }
  | UOP_NOT uexp { $$ = new ASTUExp($1,$2); }
  | T_LPAREN bexp T_LPAREN { $$ = $2; }
  | var_ref { $$ = new ASTVarRef((ASTIdentifier*)$1); }
  | call { $$ = $1; }
```

As you can see every node parsed is instantiated with the childred of the grammar, which are also semantically children of the abstract syntax tree and returned in `$$`

The root element is something like

```
start: root { Compiler::instance()->setAST((ASTRoot*)$1); }
;

root:
  function_list { $$ = new ASTRoot($1); }
;
```

in which I just get the whole tree and pass it to an instance of my `Compiler` class.

Now if you look at the function that calls `yyparse()`

```
bool parseSource()
{
  //yydebug = 1;
  freopen(fileName, "r", stdin);
  yyparse();

  return !failed;
}
```

I just open a file and call the parsing routine. This function is called by the `Compiler` class here:

```
  bool compile()
  {
    if (!parseSource())
      return false;

    if (!populateFunctionsTable())
      return false;

    ast->recursivePrint(0);
    Utils::switchStdout(binaryFile);
    ast->generateASM();
    Utils::revertStdout();

    assemble();

    return true;
  }
```

As you can see here the parsing routine is called, the routine creates the whole tree and then set it inside `Compiler` class. A recursive visit of the tree (function `generateASM`) does the dirty work.

I hope this clarifies a little bit how you should use your parser, let me know if you need any further info.. you don't need to do all the work in the parser. Just do the parsing one there, everything else can be solved with some recursive calls over your abstract syntax tree.

Another practical example is the if/else statement you are talking about, in the grammar it is defined as

```
if_stat:
  KW_IF T_LPAREN exp T_RPAREN block %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE { $$ = new ASTIfStat($3, $5); }
  | KW_IF T_LPAREN exp T_RPAREN block KW_ELSE block { $$ = new ASTIfStat($3, $5, $7); }
;
```

A special node is created, to manage the if/else construct, which then work simply by having this `generateASM` function:

```
 void generateASM()
  { 
    if (m_fbody == NULL)
    {
      m_condition->generateASM();
      printf("NOT\n");
      printf("JUMPC iflabel%u\n", labelCounter);
      m_tbody->generateASM();
      printf("iflabel%u:\r\n", labelCounter);

      ++labelCounter;
    }
    else
    {
      u32 c = labelCounter++;
      u32 d = labelCounter++;

      m_condition->generateASM();
      printf("JUMPC iflabel%u\n", c);
      m_fbody->generateASM();
      printf("JUMP iflabel%u\n", d);
      printf("iflabel%u:\n", c);
      m_tbody->generateASM();
      printf("iflabel%u:\n", d);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Having your library of classes which represent all the miscellaneous elements of your grammar is really nice because you can then work on them as much as you want. You can typecheck them, prune the tree, optimize structure and generate the ASM code all by just having some recursive visits.

Answer (score 0):

Mid-level rules can have a value pushed on the stack.

If you have

```
rule
    : A B { ... } C
```

Bison automatically converts this into

```
some_identifier
    : /* empty */ { ... }

rule
    : A B some_identifier C
```

and it's value can be accessed exactly as such. In this case, the mid-rule semantic action had a value stored on the Bison stack and then accessed again later in the same rule.

Usually, these functions are recursive. Consider the simple following snippet

```
// C++
class Statement { public: virtual ~Statement() {} };
class Expression : public Statement {};
class IfStatement : public Statement { Statement* if_true; Expression* condition; }

// Bison
%type if_statement if_stmt
%type statement stmt
%union {
    IfStatement* if_stmt;
    Statement* stmt;
}

if_statement
    : if { $$ = new IfStatement(); } 
      '(' expression { $2->condition = $4; } 
      ')' statement { $2->if_true = $7; $$ = $2; }

statement
    : if_statement { $$ = $1; }
    | ...
```

There's no need for an external stack to do recursive functionality like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare additional data to be passed around using the [`%parse-param` directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Parser-Function.html#Parser-Function). That lets you hide the extra data a bit better, though you'll have to pass it into your parsing function as well.